# Checking if a format string matches a string?

Tags: c++, string, compare

I have a string that I read from an ini file with variables that I fill at runtime. So if template string looks like `[name] has [his/her] ball at [name01]'s place`, the processed string would look like `Alice has her ball at Bob's place`.

But I'm not sure how to check if the processed string  matches the template format.

At first I thought of splitting the strings into tokens and then checking if at least 60% of the strings match but there must be a better way?

Comment: it would help if you give a few examples of your ini file and what exactly do you want to check. In the extreme case you are looking for a templating framework...

Comment: Do you have a dictionary as well to determine if the pronoun agrees with the name itself? Is that something you're supposed to check?

Comment: @Dr Phil the user can customise the template in the ini file, meaning the strings can be wildly different like ```[name] is [name01]'s friend```. I only want to run the function that fills in the variables only if the processed string doesn't match the template string. ```Alice has her ball at Bob's place``` != ```[name] is [name01]'s friend```

Comment: @CodeoftheWarrior this is for a game, but essentially I have an actor, which I then get the gender along with the reference name.Which I then fill the template

Comment: So you want to parse your ini file for tokens with a token being defined as something between [ ] ? So an example of what might be in the ini file would be like: [name] is sleeping in [place] or [ name ] and [ name1] have killed [enemy] where you are looking for a string that fits the tokens you have?

Comment: @CodeoftheWarrior but then why check if it matches the template if it is gonna be interpolated anyway...

Comment: The interpolation is done in an eventsink so I don't want to call it all the time. Only if there's a new template specified in the ini which doesn't match the string that was processed before @Dr Phil

Comment: Then you should check if your template contains square brackets. What will you do if there are unknown variables?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named [What to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What not to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read the [StackOverflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Compilable, Complete, and Verifiable Examples with a main() function](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Please provide what you have so far.

Comment: Can you show us the code you have to tokenize the strings that you are trying to process so that we can work from there?